# Copy input hidden value to other input hidden using JS

Tags: javascript, php, input, hidden

I have some input hiddens on this foreach and i need to copy these values to a other input hidden that is outside

```
<?php

$comentarios = $SQL->query("SELECT * from comentarios WHERE anime = '$get_anime' AND respostaId = 0");

foreach($comentarios as $comentario) { ?>
    <button class="replyButton" onclick="copyFormValue()">Responder</button>                        
    <input type="hidden" name="comentarioId" id="comentarioId" value="<?php echo $comentario['id']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="comentarioAvatar" value="<?php echo $comentario['avatar']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="comentarioNome" value="<?php echo $comentario['nome']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="comentarioData" value="<?php echo $comentario['data']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="comentarioTexto" value="<?php echo $comentario['comentario']; ?>">
<?php } ?>


<input type="hidden" name="respostaId" id="respostaId" value="">
            

<script>
    function copyFormValue() {
       formInput1 = document.getElementById("comentarioId");
       form2Input1 =  document.getElementById("respostaId");
       
       form2Input1.value = formInput1.value;
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that always copy the first foreach value, i need to copy the exact value reference to the button that i click..

I don't want to use post and forms to get post values..

EDIT: i put the code to be more clear to understand

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or format your code to highlight the problem you are having.

Comment: I don't see an ID being set for `comentarioId` which is what you are looking for in your function.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
                <?php foreach($comentarios as $key => $comentario) { ?>
                    <div class="comentarioBox">
                        <img src="images/avatars/<?php echo $comentario['avatar']; ?>"/>
                        <div class="comentario">
                            <div class="comentarioHeader">
                                <span class="usuario"><?php echo $comentario['nome']; ?></span><span class="data">- <?php echo $comentario['data']; ?></span>
                                <button class="replyButton" onclick="copyFormValue(<?php echo $key;?>)">Responder</button>                        
                                <input type="hidden" name="comentarioId" value="<?php echo $comentario['id']; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="comentarioAvatar" value="<?php echo $comentario['avatar']; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="comentarioNome" value="<?php echo $comentario['nome']; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="comentarioData" value="<?php echo $comentario['data']; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="comentarioTexto" value="<?php echo $comentario['comentario']; ?>">
                            </div>
                            <p><?php echo $comentario['comentario']; ?></p>
                            
                            <?php $respostasCount = $SQL->query("SELECT COUNT(*) from comentarios WHERE respostaId > 0 AND respostaId = ". $comentario['id'] ."")->fetch_row(); 
                            if ($respostasCount['0'] > 0) { ?>
                                <button class="respostas" id="respostasBox-<?php echo $comentario['id']; ?>"><?php echo $respostasCount['0']; ?> Resposta<?php echo (($respostasCount['0'] > 1) ? 's' : ''); ?></button>
                            <?php } ?>      

                            <div class="respostasComentarioBox-<?php echo $comentario['id']; ?>" style="display:none;">
                                <?php foreach($respostasComentario as $resposta) { 
                                    if ($resposta['respostaId'] == $comentario['id']) { ?>
                                        <div class="respostaComentarioBox">
                                            <img src="images/avatars/<?php echo $resposta['avatar']; ?>"/>
                                            <div class="respostaComentario">
                                                <div class="comentarioHeader">
                                                    <span class="usuario"><?php echo $resposta['nome']; ?></span><span class="data">- <?php echo $resposta['data']; ?></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <p><?php echo $resposta['comentario']; ?></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>

                <input type="hidden" name="respostaId" id="respostaId" value="">

                <script>
                    function copyFormValue(id) {
                       document.getElementById("respostaId").value = document.getElementById("comentarioId")[id].value;
                       
                    }
                </script>
```

Comment: then please try to replace id into fixed value 0, 1, 2, 3, ... maulally..

 document.getElementById("respostaId").value = document.getElementById("comentarioId")[0].value;

 document.getElementById("respostaId").value = document.getElementById("comentarioId")[1].value;
                       
...

Comment: If it works, then you can get a tip to solve this problem